# Pagination in keystoneJS can not implement it

Tags: express, pagination, keystonejs

I have many posts on my blog. I would like to show only 2 per page. I tried to use pagination in `keystoneJS`. I use https://keystonejs.com/documentation/database/#lists-paginate and should be ok, but I still see all my posts in one page.

Route / View

```
    var keystone = require('keystone')
    var Post = keystone.list('Post')

    exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
     var view = new keystone.View(req, res)
     var locals = res.locals

     // Init locals
     locals.section = 'blog'
     locals.filters = {
      post: req.params.post
     }

     // Load other posts
     view.on('init', function(next) {
       var q = Post.paginate({
        page: req.query.page,
        perPage: 2,
        maxPages: 10
      })
      .model.find()
      .where('state', 'published')
      .sort('-publishedDate')
      .populate('author')

      // .limit(4)

       q.exec(function(err, results) {
        locals.posts = results
        next(err)
      })
     })
     view.query('blog', keystone.list('Post').model.find())
     view.render('blog')
    }

blog.pug

    .pagination
            ul.pagination
                  li #{posts.totalPages}
                      a.page-num(href="?page=1") Previous

                  li
                      a.page-num(href="?page={{posts.next }}") Next
```

I see all posts on my page and I cant set a number of page in `blog.pug`.  iI was considering, if I should put any code to my `blog.pug`. Or only in route? In documentation the code is only in route file.

**EDIT**

Ok so I found the reason what has happened. I have to remove model.find() from my code in `route`. Then, in `blog.pug` I had to add to my loop word 'result'. I had 'each post in posts', and when i remove model.find() I changed my object with data.  Now it is  'each post in posts.results' and it is correct.